# Can the password for a Group Managed Service Account be retrieved programatically?

Tags: c#, winapi, active-directory, password-recovery

I have written a service that runs just fine under a gMSA account on authorized machines.  I would like to have it log into a third-party hardware device that uses RADIUS (against our own Active Directory) to authorize users.

I could always create yet another domain account specifically for this purpose and manage the password myself, but that effectively negates some of the advantages of having the gMSA in the first place.

Obviously, in order to send its own credentials, the service would need to know its own password - but the main benefit of a gMSA account is that the password is automatically managed, so that no one needs to keep track of it.  And I'm aware that, in fact, passwords don't generally exist in a retrievable state in Active Directory.

And yet - when I create a new gMSA in PowerShell with `New-ADServiceAccount`, one of the options is `-PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword`. This property typically points to a Security Group that has, as members, the computer accounts of those servers authorized to use the service account. Still, the nomenclature seems to hint that *retrieval* is technically possible.

Digging further as I think about this, I found [an author comment on this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/12/16/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts/#comment-1517) describing the complexity of the process,  but I suspect some of the steps (particularly deconstruction of the [msDS-ManagedPassword blob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881194.aspx)) are not achievable for a service account.

Come to think of it, even if I could get the password, would Network Policy Server (for example) be able to validate it when it receives it in a RADIUS Request?  I suspect those details are questions for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), but I'm really just wondering out loud if I'm barking up the wrong tree here.

I happen to be working in C#, but I wouldn't be surprised if this requires the native Windows API.

To sum up:
Is there a function call (or two or three) that will retrieve/recreate the current password for a gMSA account?

Comment: I'm guessing there isn't, but you should be able to do it using a [Credential Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374792(v=vs.85).aspx).  When the service starts up, the Credential Manager will receive the username and password.  You could save it to a file - encrypted, preferably - where the service can read it.  (You might also need some mechanism to signal the service when the password is changed, I'm not sure how that works.)